# run an application on start screen in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-8

I am stuck in a problem and need suggestions from you all.
My question is: Is it possible to run an app on start screen of a windows phone?
I have seen in android phone that there are apps like weather app in the phones start screen that opens there and there as a window on the same screen without navigation.
Can we make something like this in windows phone?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible. Though if you just want to display data, you can use Live Tiles. Live Tiles can be updated with a BackgroundAgent that runs every 30 minutes, or when the user starts the app.

See here for how BackgroundAgents work: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

And here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.shelltile(v=vs.105).aspx you would need the ShellTile.Update() Methode

Comment: that means we cant add a customized app window on the startup screen.. ??

Comment: No, you can't. Either your app is running full screen or it doens't run at all

Comment: @StefanWexel Well not quite - it could be playing audio, tracking your  location, running in the background every 30 minutes, or running hidden behind a phone call or the lock screen.

Comment: Can we show a network dashboard that contains info about all networks like bluetooth turned off or on , wifi is on of off etc etc. and also we can change the settings on the same screen??

Comment: @AmanKhandelwal Well only partly. You can get for example what network interface is currently used and if wi-fi is enabled or not and you can show that in your app, but you can't change system settings. You can however sent the user to some of the system settings pages with the `Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.ConnectionSettingsTask`